# Preferred calendar for ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, ajax

I search a good calendar for my business application.

The Microsoft ASP.NET calendar is perfect for my requirement, but I heard that this component is not longer supported by Microsoft. My apprehension is that I must in the near future program a new one.

Should I use a jQuery calendar ? Can I use a future-proof library ?

Comment: Where did you hear this? Can you post a link to your source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not the Calendar control from Ajax Control Toolkit?

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/calendar/calendar.aspx

Also why take a calendar control very seriously ;-)?? If they stop support or change something its not going to be a show stopper. you will be able to update/change easily.

Comment: +1 for the comment about not taking the calendar control too seriously! :-) Couldnt agree more!!

Answer (score 1):

you might want to design your own interface or decade class to be future-proof. i think nothing is certain in this world. In my project, jquery UI is used but i treat it as normal textbox with certain input-format string. You might want to create a custom user control in ASP .NET, therefore even you change the front end UI  with correct format; nothing need to be changed to C# code.

In my opinion, it is always adding a decade to 3th part component.

Answer (score 1):

**Take your pick from one of these [jQuery Calendar plugins](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins-for-web-designers/).**

Answer (score 1):

Calendar Extender AJAX Control Toolkit for ASP.Net 2.0 framework provides AJAX-based client-side functionality to choose the date of the extender control popup calendar.